# Menu com espaço entre li's

Tags: html, css, menu

Meu menu está com espaços entre as li's. Estou usando um css de reset, mas mesmo não precisando já tentei colocar margin: 0; e padding: 0; na ul e na ul li e não funcionou, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço. Segue o código:

https://jsfiddle.net/790zj6r4/1/

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse post, explica o erro que está tendo: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: Coloca `font-size: 0` no `ul`.

Comment: O post que o Douglas Garrido compartilhou elucida a questão, porém em minha opinião deixar a margem negativa ainda é a solução mais elegante, margin-right: -5px; no li;

Comment: Valeu! Ambas as formas funcionaram, a diferença é que a margem negativa mantém um espaço "invisível" que só é percebido ao passar o mouse por cima e o font-size elimina completamente o espaçamento

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma questão interessante, isso acontece porque com o display inline block os elementos dão um espço quando você quebra a linha do código, segue uma forma de resolver:

```css
.header-menu {
 height: auto;
}

.header-menu ul li {
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 60px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ps4.html">PS4</a></li
     ><li><a href="xboxone.html">XBOX ONE</a></li
    ><li><a href="pc.html">PC</a></li
    ><li><a href="outrosconsoles.html">Outros Consoles</a></li
    ><li><a href="esports.html">eSports</a></li
    ><li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li
    ><li><a href="videos.html">Vídeos</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Essa 'gambiarra' que eu fiz junta todas as tags sem quebra da linha, e essa margin que dava acaba, existem outras formas de resolver, da uma olhada [nesse poste do css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações como "Espero ter ajudado", pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o Stack Overflow em Português Meta :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ok obrigado :)